# Re-arranging MOnths in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel

I am trying to arrange the month columns in a pivot table for be in line with Gov't Fiscal Year (IE: First month October and last month September)
I can't seem to get excel to allow me to do that.

Is there any way to do this in excel with a Pivot table/ chart?

Thanks in advance for all assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a 'custom sort list' and then apply it to your pivot table field.

1. Create custom sort list
2. Insert pivot table
3. Apply custom sort to pivot table
4. Restore original table sort (optional)

Watch this screencast video: https://youtu.be/7ykFs5OXl2Q (90-seconds)

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I knew there was a way to do it.

I didn't need to create the Pivot table as it was already there, I just needed to do the custom sort and then apply that sort filter. 

Thanks again. 

IKE

Comment: Glad the screencast helped. Included PivotTable creation in the video to assist others who come across your question.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thanks for the video.